how to make a restriction on movement along the boundaries of the camera in unity
please help me introduce a restriction on player movement along the boundaries of the camera. At first I just used box collider 2d, but the enemies are bumping into it. And as the phone screen changes, the colliders move. How do I implement a restriction in this code? I will be very grateful for your help.
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class joystickMove : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Joystick movementjoystick;
    public float playerSpeed;
    private Rigidbody2D rb;


    private void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (movementjoystick.Direction.y != 0) 
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(movementjoystick.Direction.x * playerSpeed, movementjoystick.Direction.y * playerSpeed);
        } else 
        {
            rb.velocity = Vector2.zero;
        }
    }

I tried using box collider 2d but they shift when the phone screen changes and the enemies rest against it

Here is the code you could use.
Create a class where you want to make those calculations (for example CameraController, CameraCollider ...) and add the script to your main camera.
Then copy paste this start function, and add the field for the main camera and drag your camera inside the inspector in editor view :
[SerializeField] private Camera mainCamera;

private void Start()
{
    //Get the positions in world space of the camera bounds
    Vector3 bottomLeft = mainCamera.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0, 0, 0));
    Vector3 topRight = mainCamera.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(1, 1, 0));

    //Create a new GameObject with a BoxCollider2D
    GameObject cameraBounds = new GameObject("CameraBounds");
    cameraBounds.AddComponent<BoxCollider2D>();

    //Set the position of the BoxCollider2D to the center of the camera bounds
    cameraBounds.transform.position = new Vector3((topRight.x + bottomLeft.x) / 2, (topRight.y + bottomLeft.y) / 2, 0);

    //Set the size of the BoxCollider2D to match the camera bounds
    BoxCollider2D boxCollider = cameraBounds.GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
    boxCollider.size = new Vector2(topRight.x - bottomLeft.x, topRight.y - bottomLeft.y);
}

This code is doing the following things :

Assign the camera to use from the inspector (SerializeField makes it possible to assign variables from editor without having to make them public)
Use the function ViewPortToWorldPoint to get the bounds of the camera view. This function takes as parameter coordinates between 0 and 1 (so for example, (0,0) is bottom left, (1,1) is top right, (0,1) is top left, (0.5,0.5) is middle etc no matter what is the size of your camera view and of the screen)
Once we have the coordinates of the topLeft and bottomRight of the field of view of the camera, then we create a new GameObject in the scene, assign a box collider2D to it, and set its center to be the center of the camera and its size to be the difference between the x coordinates of the bounds for the width, and the difference between the y coordinates of the bounds for the eight. Just a bit of Maths :)

Fell free to ask if you have any questions, there are no dumb ones

the collider is created clearly along the boundaries of the camera, but my player does not rest against it and does not interact with it in any way. Could it be related to my tag system?

if I uncheck "This is a trigger" in the box collider field of my player, then at the very beginning it flies out of the camera and rests against the collider created with your code

Then it might be a problem with how you have setup your colliders (and rigibodies if you have some eventually).
Its a bit tricky when you are just a beginner so if you want you can share some screens of your setup and i might be able to help you with that

as I understand it, the collider is created according to the size of the entire camera, but it is necessary that it be created along the boundaries of the camera and be like a wall

yes, with the code i sent you its supposed to be along the boundaries of the camera, if you hit play and go to the scene view you should see a new gameobject spawn and if you click on it you will see the bounds of the collider created.

and how to do the opposite? so that the collider is created around the camera and serves as a wall so that the player cannot go outside the camera.

Oh i see my mistake now, i will send you and updated version of the code

Here is the version that prevents players or anything to move outside of the camera field, feel free to ask if you have any questions on how this code works.
[SerializeField] private Camera mainCamera;

private void Start()
{
    //Get the positions in world space of the camera bounds
    Vector3 bottomLeft = mainCamera.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0, 0, 0));
    Vector3 topRight = mainCamera.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(1, 1, 0));

    //Create 4 box colliders, one for each side of the camera to prevent the player from leaving the camera bounds
    GameObject left = new GameObject("Left");
    left.transform.position = new Vector3(bottomLeft.x - 0.5f, 0, 0);
    left.AddComponent<BoxCollider2D>().size = new Vector2(1, topRight.y - bottomLeft.y);

    GameObject right = new GameObject("Right");
    right.transform.position = new Vector3(topRight.x + 0.5f, 0, 0);
    right.AddComponent<BoxCollider2D>().size = new Vector2(1, topRight.y - bottomLeft.y);

    GameObject top = new GameObject("Top");
    top.transform.position = new Vector3(0, topRight.y + 0.5f, 0);
    top.AddComponent<BoxCollider2D>().size = new Vector2(topRight.x - bottomLeft.x, 1);

    GameObject bottom = new GameObject("Bottom");
    bottom.transform.position = new Vector3(0, bottomLeft.y - 0.5f, 0);
    bottom.AddComponent<BoxCollider2D>().size = new Vector2(topRight.x - bottomLeft.x, 1);

    //Make all of the colliders children of the camera
    left.transform.SetParent(mainCamera.transform);
    right.transform.SetParent(mainCamera.transform);
    top.transform.SetParent(mainCamera.transform);
    bottom.transform.SetParent(mainCamera.transform);
}

You can also put all this code inside a CalculateColliders() function or something like this, so that you can call it on game start and whenever you want.
